# How to pivot select columns under a new column by sampling values from the original dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, pivot

This is my dataframe:

[image]

How I want my result dataframe:

[image]

Note: from the original dataframe I've removed two rows of feed values for sex F as it's higher in number than M. I want to take a sample of values from the first dataframe before pivoting for the 'F' values but keep the original amount of data for the 'M' values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to sample the rows by sex to have maximum 3 rows:

```
out = (df.sample(frac=1) # suffle rows
         .groupby('sex').head(3) # pick max 3 per group
         # reshape
         .melt(['id', 'sex'], value_name='weight', var_name='feed')
      )
```

Output:

```
    id sex       feed  weight
0    1   F  horsebean      23
1    6   M  horsebean      50
2    4   F  horsebean      42
3    5   F  horsebean      20
4    1   F    linseed      10
5    6   M    linseed      20
6    4   F    linseed      10
7    5   F    linseed      10
8    1   F  sunflower      16
9    6   M  sunflower      15
10   4   F  sunflower      15
11   5   F  sunflower      15
```